# Positioning toolbar location inside a datagridview using C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, pagination

I am creating a datagridview with a pagination toolbar docked to the bottom of the datagridview. When the data source is refreshed, the horizontal scroll bar is not displayed properly.  The tool bar is drawn behind the horizontal scroll bar.

This is a screenshot when the datagridview loads properly or shows only set data.
[image]

This is a screenshot when the datagridview does not load properly.  This seems to happen when the data grid loads various sets of data based on another datagridview.
[image]

I created a method to redraw the toolbar.

```
public void reloadPagination()
    {
            int horizontalScroolBarHeight = this.HorizontalScrollBar.Visible ? this.HorizontalScrollBar.Height : 0;
            int verticalScroolBarWidth = this.VerticalScrollBar.Visible ? this.VerticalScrollBar.Width : 0;

            _pagination.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, this.Height - horizontalScroolBarHeight - _pagination.Height);

            _pagination.panelRight.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.Width - _pagination.panelRight.Width - 1, _pagination.panelRight.Location.Y);

            UpdateSortButton();
        }

    }
```

I tried to call this method in `protected override void OnDataBindingComplete(DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)`. If HorizontalScrollBar.Visible is set to false, then the toolbar is drawn behind the horizontal scroll bar.

Is there another event I can call in order to refresh pagination toolbar?

Let me know if there is anything I can add to this post clarify the issue.

Comment: I am not sure “why” you would want to add a pagination toolbar “INTO” the grid itself. I would think that putting the toolbar “INTO” the grid itself, is going to create a lot of extra work to display all the data properly in the grid. Hence the horizontal scroll bar covering the tool bar. I would think the toolbar “outside” the grid would be easier to implement and if “properly” placed, would give the “appearance” that it is part of the grid.

Comment: You state that… _”The tool bar is drawn behind the horizontal scroll bar.”_ … and this is correct as it should be. The scrollbar would be of little use if something IN the grid covered it up. Is there some reason you MUST put the tool bar INTO the grid?

Comment: Hi JohnG,  I am trying to make it look make it look like the tool bar is part of the grid.  I can try to position the tool bar below the grid.

Comment: I can assure you that it will be much less work if you put the tool bar above or below the grid. If you butt it up to the grid, it could “look” like it was part of the grid. FYI, are you aware .Net has a built-in control called [BindingNavigator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/bindingnavigator-control-overview-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) that may help you by building the tool bar navigation buttons etc. An example using the [BindingNavigator Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator?view=net-5.0)